# Python ndArray Generation [Different Data Type Columns]

Tags: python, numpy, timestamp, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to generate a ndArray to compare it with an existing one, which is structured as follow:

- the first column dtype is 'datetime' (Timestamp('2020-08-29 00:00:00))
- all the other n columns dtype are 'float' (nan)

The way I found till now is to define the array as:

`dataset = np.array((timestamp_vector, nan_vector, nan_vector, ...), dtype=object)`

I do not want to repeat 'nan_vector' n-time. Do you have some advice?

Comment: What's the dtype of the existing one?

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, same dtype: the first column dtype is 'datetime' (Timestamp('2020-08-29 00:00:00)) and all the other n columns dtype are 'float' (nan). I got this ndArray from a .csv data importation.

Comment: You can make a new array with the dtype of the original, e.g. `np.zeros((3,), dtype=existing.dtype)`.  You can set values by field, or with a list of tuples.  But I should warn you that comparing structured arrays is difficult.  Measures like `==` and `-` are not defined for compound dtypes.  You have to do the comparisons (and any math) on individual fields.

Comment: If the array loads as a label/datetime field followed by a lot of float fields, you might want to load it with a different `dtype`, e.g. `np.dtype([('time', 'U20'), ('data', float, 47)]`).  This will have two fields, one with the label, and the other with an array of floats.  Or load the file twice, one with `usecols=[0]`, and again with all the rest.

Answer (score -1):

To improve the above ndarray construction, I made a *for loop* where I used the *concatenate function* to add a new *nan* array, previously created with the same length of *timestamp* vector.